# What is the best way to run a specific set of queries in order?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have 50 or so queries that all need to be run in a specific order.  I just want to set up a Procedure that will run them in the order I need.  Is there a way to call the .sql files I have saved as I don't want to have to make changes each month to one large lump of code?  I'd prefer to make changes to each specific query as needed that way the Procedure does not need to be modified.

Comment: You can create 50 or so stored procedures and then another one to execute them in the order you want. This way, you still separate each procedure and don't have to maintain a huge code dump.

Comment: How do I make my queries into stored procs and then how do I write a proc to execute them?

Comment: That depends on the rdbms you are working with. it's different syntax for MySql, Oracle, SQL Server etc'.

Comment: Sorry, I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: [Start here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a stored procedure you can write a **SQLCMD** script that will execute .sql files stored on the file system:

```
:setvar path "c:\path_to_your_sql_files"
:on error exit

USE [YOUR_DB_NAME]
GO

SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION

    go
    :r $(path)/"SCRIPT001.sql"
    go
    :r $(path)/"SCRIPT002.sql"
    go
    :r $(path)/"SCRIPT003.sql"
    go

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

If you run this inside **SSMS** remember to enable "*SQLCMD Mode*" inside "*Query*" menu.